# Reusable component for vue-tags-input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently using this UI component from http://www.vue-tags-input.com

I'm planning to create a reusable component for vue-tags-input, here's my current code:

**components/UI/BaseInputTag.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-form-group :label="label">
    <no-ssr>
      <vue-tags-input
        :value="tags"
        @tags-changed="updateValue"/>
    </no-ssr>
  </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'BaseInputTag',
    props:   {
      label: { type: String, required: true },
      value: { type: [String, Number, Array] },
      tags: { type: [Array] }
    }, 
    methods: {
      updateValue(newTags) {
        this.$emit('input', newTags);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and in my parent vue page. I'm calling above component with this code:

**pages/users/new.vue**

```
<BaseInputTag v-model="tag" :tags="interests" label="Interests"/>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'InsiderForm',
    data() {
      return {
        tag: '', 
        interests: []
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I emit back the child component's `newTags` to parent's data `interests`

Comment: If you're looking to create reusable ui components, this is a good read https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work, here's my code:

**child-component**

```
<template>
  <b-form-group :label="label">
    <no-ssr>
      <vue-tags-input
        :value="value"
        v-model="tag"
        placeholder="Add Tag"
        :tags="tags"
        @tags-changed="updateValue"/>
    </no-ssr>
  </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'BaseInputTag',
    props:   {
      label: { type: String, required: true },
      value: { type: [String, Number, Array] },
      tags: { type: [Array, String] },
      validations: { type: Object, required: true }
    }, 
    data() {
      return {
        tag: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateValue(newTags) {
        this.$emit('updateTags', newTags);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and to receive the changes to parent component:

```
<BaseInputTag :tags="interests" @updateTags="interests = $event" label="Interests"/>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'InsiderForm',
    data() {
      return {
        tag: '', 
        interests: []
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah thats fine, I just worked with what You gave me. Mark the answer as accepted, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there!

Parent component:

```
<BaseInputTag v-model="tag" :tags="interests" @input="doStuffWithChildValue" label="Interests"/>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'InsiderForm',
    data() {
      return {
        tag: '', 
        interests: []
      };
    },
    methods: {
      doStuffWithChildValue (value) {
        console.log('Got value from child', value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Karolis, do I still need the @tags-changed from the child component to emit the parent component?

Comment: Yup, Your child component listens to `@tags-changed` event, and then emits it's data to the parent. Parent listens for it with the `@input` event and executes a method to console.log the value.

Comment: Thanks Karolis. I managed to make it work based on your suggestion,  but I . made a little tweaks. I'll post my code